# structure booking system with different types of entities

Tags: database-design

I have a booking service with different types of entities.
For example: `booking_restaurants` and `booking_houses`.

I was thinking about 2 different designs.

- 1 booking table (`booking` with 3 columns, `id`, `id_restaurant` nullable, `id_house` nullable)
- 2 booking tables (`restaurant_booking` and `house_booking`).

The booking have some similar fields, and some different fields. I am not sure about the 2 ideas, but I would choice the second one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141873/database-design-how-to-handle-subclass-superclass

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the number 1.

Eventually one day you will also need to provide a golf field. What will you do in that case? Create a `golf_booking` table?

Stick with the [Database design star schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/star-schema):

[image]

The main center of the design of your database should be a table called `booking` if the main goal of your database is storing information about bookings.

In that same table the first two columns will be:

- `id`: an incremental number
- `id_venue`: a numeric column which is a Foreign Key to another table called `venue`.

Overall the `booking` table will look like this:

| id | id_venue |
| --- | --- |
| 23654 | 1 |
| 23656 | 1 |
| 23567 | 2 |
| 23568 | 1 |
| 23569 | 1 |
| 23570 | 1 |
| 23571 | 3 |
| 23572 | 1 |
| 23573 | 1 |
| 23564 | 1 |

In the `venue` table you will have:

| id | id_venue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | restaurants |
| 2 | houses |
| 3 | golf |

This way, 5 years from now, if you need to provide more services to your customers you only need to add 1 raw in the `venue` table.

Let me know if this is clear or if you need more info.

Comment: it seems reasonable, but it shouldn't be exactly my first option, right? In this case I do not have to add columns in the booking table for future new entities, but just a row in the "entities" (you called them "venue") table. and that's better.
What about if I am in microservices? if in the future I will have a microservive for golf booking, one for house booking, ecc. Could, in that case, it be better the second option?

Comment: ....mmm... I would still say no. Try to imagine to have a single tenant infrastructure: a microservice for restaurant, one for houses and one for golf. in this case you will create a table restaurant, a table houses and a table golf. A different table for microservice... 
...and now you have 3 different software to maintain. And this is bad.

Comment: I am not agree with this. The logic of microservices is exactly that. Having small projects to mantain. Of course you must be very conscious about if there are differences among microservices. But if the booking processes are different, I would put them in different microservices

Comment: No, the logic of microservices is to have 1000 microservices, they are all the same, and you can adapt them to customer 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 1000. And the good side is that you only have to maintain 1 application and sell it like pancake. But once you have 2 databases with a different schema you now have 2 applications. And you need to provide 2 different microservices,  once for restaurants and one for houses